# Splitting Titles in DropDown

Tags: asp.net-2.0

My application Drop-down consist of lengthy titles, which exceeds the drop-down beyond the page.

Example Title:
Enter your Name Up to 250 Char Enter your Name Up to 250 Char Enter your Name Up to 250 Char Enter your Name Up to 250 Char.

i can split half of the title with sub string().
Is it possible to bring the next half of the title to next line in Drop-down using C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any property of the DropDownList control that allows you to wrap text, but when I've had items in a DropDownList that exceed the width of the control, I add a tooltip that displays the full text of the item when the mouse hovers over it.

You can do this in code-behind after you've populated the DropDownList:

C#

```
foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)   
    item.Attributes.Add("Title", item.Text);
```

VB

```
For Each item As ListItem In DropDownList1.Items
    item.Attributes.Add("Title", item.Text)
End For
```

Comment: i think,the above code will just adds items to Drop-down list.

Comment: @Mike - it adds the HTML <title> attribute to the items in the drop down list - this is the same as adding a tooltip so that when you hover over the item, you see the full text.